# Draw rectangle over ViewPager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-canvas

I have a ViewPager which dispalys images from url.but i want to draw rectangle over the image in ViewPager . I dont know how to implement this. I tried to do this in PagerAdapter. My try given belowbut not giving any result

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_image, view, false);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        imageNameDisplay.setText(imageNames.get(position));


        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

         Paint paint = new Paint();
         paint.setColor(Color.RED);
         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(110);
         float leftx = 20;
         float topy = 20;
         float rightx = 50;
         float bottomy = 50;
         canvas.drawRect(leftx, topy, rightx, bottomy, paint);
         ........
         .........
         }
```

Please guide me ..

Comment: You can try with XML code instead of java..

Comment: i want create the  rectangle dynamically..

Answer (score 0):

**I want to draw rectangle over the image**

You can keep one more View over the ImageView and you can set the background of that View or you can handle the visibility of that view from java code..

Hope this can help you..

Any specific reason to draw by java code?

Comment: yes i want to draw  the rectangle on certain positions like tagging in Facebook.. Rectangle should drawn in specified x y co ordinates..